# how use the mathematical statement in FROM in the sql query

Tags: mysql

I want the sum of one column which is already derived by another two column multiplication below i am mentioning the query please let me know the solution

```
(select SUM(Multiplication) as weight from ( s.qtyonhand *  ROUND((sysdate - inv.movementdate), 2 ))),

  s.qtyonhand *  ROUND((sysdate - inv.movementdate), 2) as Multiplication
```

Above query giving the error that missing right parenthesis
please help me out

Comment: remove `(` before `select` it is not nessesary.

Comment: give us your full query. The FROM statement looks fishy to me. I would expect a table name there, not a number.

Comment: multiplication column is not available in any table , its created by using another two column